# Change value in php

Tags: php

```
// $tags can be a string with comma separated values, such as: 
// $tags = 'first, second, third';
```

How can i add a tag to this php code through a form. I want to enter a value in the form and then it will be added to the `$tags` then it has to redirect me to another page?

Comment: How do you expect to store the initial value of $tags through the reload.  Are you putting it in the form field?

Comment: Are you storing `$tags`? What have you got? What have you tried? See, I shouldn't be asking these questions, you need to include more detail.

Comment: Terms to lookup: form, method post/get, sessions, header().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On form action page

```
$next_value = $_POST['fildvalue'];
$tags .=','.$next_value;
header('location:url') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$tags=array();
$tags[]="first";
$tags[]="second";
$tags[]="third";

array_push($tags,$_GET["tag"]);
$nTags=implode(",",$tags);
$nTags=urlencode($nTags);
header("Location : http://example.com/?tags=$nTags");
?>
```